# Django-rq-scheduler: call function with arguments from django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, django-rq

We are using django 1.10, django-rq, django-rq-scheduler.

In the django admin one can set a callable function, but how is it possible to send specific param-values to that function (e.g. in the screenshot call dir_listener.dir_scanner.scan_all_directories(3, 'kuku') )?

[image: django admin rq-scheduler]

Thank you

Comment: This is an old question - in new versions it is